# Save a file as a BLOB with Doctrine

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Symfony2 with Doctrine 2.2.2 and a Oracle Database. I want to save a file as a BLOB in the Oracle DB. I wrote a costum Type for Doctrine to have a BLOB Type. It look's like this:

```
class Blob extends Type
{
const BLOB = 'blob';


public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return (is_resource($value)) ? stream_get_contents($value) : $value;
}

public function getSqlDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return 'BLOB';
}

public function getBindingType() {
    return \PDO::PARAM_LOB;
}

public function getName()
{
    return self::BLOB;
}
}
```

The entity which holds the file is the following:

```
<?php

class Document
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var file $file
 */
private $file;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set file
 *
 * @param blob $file
 */
public function setFile($file)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

/**
 * Get file
 *
 * @return blob 
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}
}
```

When I want to save the file with my Controller Doctrine only saves the Path to the temp-File which will be created when uploading the file.

Comment: have you find any solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the $file variable is not a resource.

You could try this:

```
public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return is_file($value) ? file_get_contents($value) : $value;
}
```

Comment: No, this does not work either. Doctrine only saves the Path to the temporary uploaded file and gives this Path back when I want to download it from the database.

Comment: Are you sure your blob type is correctly registered and used?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a blob type in doctrine 2.2 here Doctrine\DBAL\Types\BlobType